# How to create a pd.DatatimeIndex with a list of dates and a certain time?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of pd.Timestamps whose time information is zero. i.e. `Timestamp('2011-04-01 00:00:00')`
and I would like to convert them to a list of timestamp with specific time say `Timestamp('2011-04-01 10:30:00')`. How do I do that in pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `Timedelta`:

```
In [248]: pd.Timestamp('2011-04-01 00:00:00') + pd.Timedelta('10:30:00')
Out[248]: Timestamp('2011-04-01 10:30:00')
```

If it is `DatetimeIndex` solution is similar:

```
df.index + pd.Timedelta('10:30:00')
```

Comment: The input is actually a DatetimeIndex not a single timestamp. Is there a better way of doing what you suggested for every element of the index using a for loop?